# What do the numbers within a `sequence` of the ASN.1 syntax mean?

Tags: asn.1

Here is an example:

```
 TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
     serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
     signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
     issuer               Name,
     validity             Validity,
     subject              Name,
     subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
     issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                          -- If present, version must be v2 or v3
     subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                          -- If present, version must be v2 or v3
     extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                          -- If present, version must be v3
     }
```

What do the numbers `[0]`, `[1]`, ... mean, when are they needed and what does the absence of such a number mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called tag numbers and they are used (along with the word EXPLICIT or IMPLICIT that can follow) to encode / decode the TBSCertificate value when a TLV (Tag Length Value) form is used (for example ASN.1 Basic Encoding Rules)

The text you show is call a specification and describe a type (TBSCertificate). Actually, this is just a portion of specification as you are missing the definition of Version, CerficateSerialNumber, etc ..

The specification is a human readable text.

By the time you want to instantiate values, you must know which encoding will be used (ASN.1 defines a few of them, binary and textual)

The oldest binary encoding is called Basic Encoding Rules and uses a TLV form.

Normally, as a user, you need not understand the details of encoding. You should use a tool that creates some code from the specification.

For me, allowing tags in the specification was a huge mistake that was made in the very beginning of ASN.1. It mixes 2 completely different things (specification and encoding).

That was solved later with what is called AUTOMATIC tagging but the damage was done.

Comment: There's still a use for manual production tags in systems where the totality of the schemas isn't compiled into a single output, ie different subsystems get different schema files to use. Automatic tagging then is a liability because the compilers start with zero and work from there in the order they come across productions. That's less than helpful if different subsystems have got the same production via a different sequence of IMPORTs; the automatic assignment will be different. Manual tagging sorts this out but then becomes a bit like managing line numbers in old fashioned BASICA.